# What is !0 converted to when compared using == in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, comparison, conditional-statements

I was tring a few things in the console.

```
!5 is actually false
0 is a falsy value, so
0 == !5 is true
```

Okay, but when i tried this

```
!0 is true
5 is a truthy, so
5 == !0 should be true
```

But its not, the console says false. **Why is this happening?**

Comment: *5 will get converted to false*  ?

Comment: How does the question you linked to relate to your question?

Comment: Because (5 == !0) is equivalent to (5 == true), which is false.

Comment: @j08691 it was just for background, its the reason why I tried the things in the console.

Comment: The statement `5 will get converted to false, so` makes no sense to me. There's no reason why `5 == !0` should be true. Its comparing 5 to true, which is false.

Comment: @j08691 More specifically `5 == 1` is false. The moral of the story is don't rely on `==` to do the conversion that you expect it to OP, it's quite funky.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, I just realized the typo, what I meant was 5 will get converted to true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the last line is `false` is that the `==` isn't a simple boolean conversion. It *usually* tries to convert operands with non-matching types down to a number.

So the `5` doesn't need conversion since it's already a number but `!0`, which is `true`, does. The value `true` gets converted to `1`, so it doesn't equal `5`.

You can infer from this that `1 == !0` will be `true`, and indeed it is.

This is detailed in the ES5 spec in the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), step 7, which says of the comparison `x == y`:

> If Type(*y*) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison *x* == ToNumber(*y*).

So the right-hand boolean is coerced to a number with [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3). In this case, ToNumber says:

> The result is **1** if the argument is **true**.

Comment: Oh! yes `1 == !0` gives true.

Comment: `x == ToNumber(y)` would happen only if x is a number isn't it?

Comment: @AkshendraPratap: Sort of. The algorithm is recursive. So `x` could start off as something else but have been converted to a number on an earlier pass.